# cannot update an existing lambda with serverless 1.x

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

We have several aws stacks that were deployed using Node 4 and serverless 0.5 and now we are trying to move to Node 6 and serverless 1.x. We have migrated the configuration (serverless.yml) and all, but our problem comes when we try to update the actual stack.

Serverless fails at the actual lambda update process with an error like this:

`An error occurred: GroupDashshipmentsLambdaFunction - xxx-manifest-service-group-shipments already exists.` .

I know it may be possible to go in and delete the lambdas one by one, but on a production environment this is not really a good thing to do. How can I tell serverless to go ahead and update those lambdas

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your Cloudformation stack name the same in the 1.x version as it is in the 0.5 version? If the lambda already exists in a stack, you won't be able to create it in another

Comment: @bwinant, yes, the stack names and lambda names are the same...